# Scala load file from disk and resources if fails

Tags: io

I am new to Scala and developing a RESTful API using Scala and Akka and need to read the binding configuration from XML file which has following section.

```
<appconfig>
   <bindproperties>
     <host>localhost</host>
     <port value="7777"/>
   </bindproperties>
</appconfig>
```

I want to verify and read this file from disk first if it exists and load it. If it doesn't exist then I want to load from default Resource path. Currently, I am doing as following:

```
val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/config/PreferencesServiceConfiguration.xml")
val appSettings = scala.xml.XML.load(stream)

def bindHost : String = { (appSettings \ "bindproperties" \ "host").text.toString }
def bindPort : Int = {    (appSettings \ "bindproperties" \ "port" \ "@value").toString.toInt  }
```

But this always reads from Resource file embedded into JAR file, but not from disk.

Can anyone please guide me how can I do that? I want logic flow as below:

- if xml file exists in classpath/config folder

  - load XML file as AppSettings
- else

  - Load Default Resource XML file (embedded as Resource in JAR) as AppSettings
- Read properties from AppSettings

Answer (score 0):

As a better alternative, use Config (com.typesafe.Config) to load the configuration. You can have your default configuration as reference.conf. All the settings that you have mentioned, can be put into this configuration file.

However, if you'd like to load the XML file from the disk. I would suggest, at run-time do configuration checks at standard locations (including deployed directory or relative paths to the deployed directory). If this check fails, you can fallback to embedded resource.

Again Config scores above this as you can define a fallback if external configuration is not supplied.